# Редирект с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Здравствуйте!

Сайт имеет страницы вида `site.ru/page.php`

Проблема в том, что если дописать что-нибудь после .php со слешем, например, 
site.ru/page.php/smth, то страница не изменится, а нужно, чтобы возвращалась 404.

**Вопрос:** как это сделать? Пытаюсь решить с помощью htaccess редиректом на 404, пока не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# правило реагирует на запрос содержащий подстроку ".php/" и любой символ за слешем
# если наличие символа после слеша не нужно проверять, то последнюю точку надо удалить
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php/.
# перенаправление на страницу с ошибкой 404
# на Apache 2.4 работает, на боле ранних версиях не проверял
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```